# Is there a British equivalent for "Monday morning quarterback"?

Tags: british-english, idiom-requests

Is there a British or general English (as opposed to Americanism) equivalent for "[Monday morning quarterback](https://www.yourdictionary.com/monday-morning-quarterback)" that describes someone who acts as if they had known the result of something all along. Or someone who criticizes something after the fact.

> She is playing a Monday morning quarterback and acting as if she had seen it coming.

or

> He always plays the Monday morning quarterback and tells us what we should have done.

Comment: The saying *"Hindsight is 20-20"* comes to mind, although that doesn't refer to a person specifically.

Comment: Possibly "smart Alec", but it doesn't have the hindsight connotation.

Comment: Related: [expression or idiom for a person who knows every detail about something](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/277332/expression-or-idiom-for-a-person-who-knows-every-detail-about-something)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a phrase or a word for someone who says "I knew that would happen" after the fact?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152857/what-is-a-phrase-or-a-word-for-someone-who-says-i-knew-that-would-happen-after)

Comment: 'Captain hindsight' in the [linked question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/152910/365490) is probably the best one.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, Just because there's a duplicate, doesn't mean the question and answer here deserve downvotes.

Comment: @Decapitated Soul Exactly the same answers (and 'Monday morning quarterback') are given there. The downvotes are to discourage lack of checking, and to encourage deletion/closure here. Are you saying that duplication is _useful_? Why do you think  the 'duplicate' close-vote exists. _And if you're so bothered about (your reading of adhering to) site protocol, why haven't you added a close-vote?_

Comment: I would expect something like "tea-time batsman".

Comment: @RiversMcForge - "Twenty-twenty hindsight" will have a whole new meaning come January first!

Comment: @HotLicks Then you would be disappointed. As a Brit I find it strange that the identification with a player should be used to indicate hindsight, and know of no such Expression in British English. This sort of identification of spectator with “actor” is seen in “back-seat driver” but has quite a different meaning. There may be a similar sporting expression indicating an amateur talking as if he were an expert, but it escapes me for the moment.

Comment: @David - I suspect you need to understand American football better.  While there are coaches, the "quarterback" is the guy on the field who ultimately decides how each scrimmage will be played.  So his ability to think ahead and plan is critical to a well-played game.  A "Monday morning quarterback" is that guy in the office who is telling everyone how screwed up the quarterback's decisions were and how much better the game would have been played if only the office guy were making the decisions.

Answer (score 1):

[Be wise after the event](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/to-be-wise-after-the-event):

> used to mean that it us easy to understand what you could  have done to prevent something bad from happening after it has happened.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

The expressions derived from former popular proverbs:

> ... the three following historical variants of a proverb of prudence: “*it is good to be wise before the mischief*”  (1584) *“after the business is over every one is wise”*, (1666) and “*it is easy to be wise after the event*” (1900) with the latter form having become today’s standard from 1935.

[Proverbs, a Handbook](https://books.google.it/books?id=rfWFu5C-tL0C&pg=PA9&dq=%22wise%20after%20the%20event%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDw6GBtOjrAhVGs4sKHZF3DSYQ6AEwAXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22wise%20after%20the%20event%22&f=false) by Wolfgang Mieder